# My screen was frozen after using "Apply Now"

Tags: bug, status-norepro, stack-overflow-jobs

My screen got *frozen* after I clicked on "`Apply Now`" button for a particular position and filled in the required data. After that the screen was darkened and there was an empty white box in the middle.

The careers site shows that I applied for the position and I got e-mail response stating the same. It lets me to believe that the request reached the back-end and then something happened on the front-end, possibly during confirmation.

My browser: Google Chrome ver. 47.0.2526.106 m

**EDIT**:

This time I managed to capture the screen:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I'm not able to reproduce this. I clicked Apply Now for a job on stackoverflow.com/jobs and the dialog correctly displayed the Apply Form. Did this occur on stackoverflow.com/jobs or on careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs? Did the Apply Form load in the white box at all, and did you submit anything through it? Or did it simply stay white (which would simply astonish me that careers would then indicate you applied for the position)? What "confirmation" are you referring to?

Comment: The small white box on a darkened background was frozen after I **submitted** the data.  If it happens again I will capture the image.

Comment: Thanks! We're seeing some items in our exception log that might be related to this - still investigating...

Comment: @PM77-1 We're still unable to repro this, has it happened since?

Comment: @DeanWard - I have not used this functionality since.

Comment: @DeanWard - Yes, it's still happening to me. Please see the screen capture I added to the post.

Comment: @G-Wiz - This time I did capture the screen.